# Grouping blocks of rows and sorting by column that contains replicates

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I wanted to come back with the question properly asked and thank timeless and stackoverflow! I was asked to make my question I/O readable. That actually solved my problem. I threw this into my chatgpt

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['01p','seq01,Inj1','0.0825','446','Name','1'],
                  ['01p','seq01,Inj2','0.0560','446','Name','1'],
                  ['01p','seq01,Inj1','0.6789','445','IDZA','3'],
                  ['01p','seq01,Inj2','0.2323','445','IDZA','3'],
                  ['01p','seq01,Inj1','0.4678','359','IDA','2'],
                  ['01p','seq01,Inj2','0.0214','359','IDA','2'],
                  ['02p','seq02,Inj1','0.9999','335','BOC','5'],
                  ['02p','seq02,Inj2','0.1111','335','BOC','5'],
                  ['02p','seq02,Inj1','0.1234','446','FOO','4'],
                  ['02p','seq02,Inj2','0.5812','446','FOO','4']],
                  columns =['Acq. Name', 'Sample Name', 'A','M', 'C', 'Use_Index'])
```

Told it I wanted this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['01p','seq01,Inj1','0.0825','446','Name','1'],
                  ['01p','seq01,Inj2','0.0560','446','Name','1'],
                  ['01p','seq01,Inj1','0.4678','359','IDA','2'],
                  ['01p','seq01,Inj2','0.0214','359','IDA','2'],
                  ['01p','seq01,Inj1','0.6789','445','IDZA','3'],
                  ['01p','seq01,Inj2','0.2323','445','IDZA','3'],
                  ['02p','seq02,Inj1','0.1234','446','FOO','4'],
                  ['02p','seq02,Inj2','0.5812','446','FOO','4'],
                  ['02p','seq02,Inj1','0.9999','335','BOC','5'],
                  ['02p','seq02,Inj2','0.1111','335','BOC','5']],
                  columns =['Acq. Name', 'Sample Name', 'A','M', 'C', 'Use_Index'])
```

And after some chat got this that worked. woohoo!

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df2.columns)  # create an empty DataFrame

for group, data in df2.groupby('Use_Index'):
    sorted_data = data.sort_values(by=['M', 'C'], ascending=[True, False])
    sorted_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    sorted_data['Use_Index'] = group
    df3 = pd.concat([df3, sorted_data])

df4 = df3
print(df4)
```

Comment: `df["Use_Index"] = df.groupby("M", sort=False).ngroup().add(1)` ?

Comment: Hi, I will try this. Sometimes "M" also has replicates. I am not sure why my question was closed.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, please make sure to update your question by providing the I/O (*a clear input and the exact matching expected output*) as texts : [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Hi Timeless, It didn't work.

And Do you mean how I copy the data into my post? Ok. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I see your point! My post is really annoying. I'm so used to jut pulling in excel files. I"m going to do this right and come back